# makefiles - the clean as target

Tags: gcc, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

can anyone tell me how to execute the clean target which is written in the makefile.
here is my code

```
jamm : hello.o ghola.o
    gcc $^ -o $@

%.o : %.c
    gcc -c S<

clean :  
    rm *.c
```

i have some questions.how to clean all those c files using the clean as target. we give the command make -f file1(say filename is file1) and it sees the target as jamm and execute but it wont execute the clean target.If in the command line i say make clean it says no such file or directory i'm unable to get this concept can anyone please tell me how to execute these clean when i have written in my make file.please guyss

Comment: please at least format your sample make file.

Comment: it doesn't look like you have a clean target in that make file anyway

Comment: ok i do it but no matter how i try i dont know how to set it in a format

Comment: did you try "make -f file1 clean" ?

Comment: not really so is it that's the way to do clean?

Answer (score 4):

Check in your directory if you have a file named "*clean*".
It might be that your `make` call thinks it must *generate* a "clean" file somehow.

To fix this, try to add just before your clean target a [.PHONY indicator](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Phony-Targets.html):

```
jamm : hello.o ghola.o
    gcc $^ -o $@

%.o : %.c
    gcc -c S<

# add this:
.PHONY: clean

clean :  
    rm *.c
```

**BY THE WAY: YOUR CLEAN TARGET LOOKS BAD: shouldn't you delete the .o files instead of the .c ????**

Answer (score 2):

In one of my makefiles, the `clean` target looks like this:

```
.PHONY: depend clean all new

clean:
    rm *.o *~ $(PROGS) ~/include/*.gch
```

Note that the line with the executable statement begins with a tab.

Some other things:

1. You probably don't want to `rm` your `.c` files.  Those are your source files, and you could lose all your work coding them.
2. What you do want to remove are your object (`.o` in my example) and executable (`$(PROGS)` in my example, really any variable that contains the names of the executables) files, and precompiled headers (`.gch`), so you can remake from a clean slate.
3. Targets that don't actually produce a file by that name, like `clean`, should be listed as prerequisites of `.PHONY`.  This lets make know that even if there is a file called `clean`, it should run the command anyway.
4. To execute a particular target (`clean` for example), just enter

   ```
   make clean
   ```

   but make sure that:

   - You are in the same directory as your makefile
   - Your makefile needs to be named `Makefile` or `makefile`. If you are using GNU make, you can also call it `GNUmakefile`